# Is there any way to enter a "while" loop while a boolean value is false

Tags: python

I'm basically running a code that builds up an address book into a text file through user entries.

While doing so, I'm checking to see if the inputed information is correct and, in the case that it's not, asking them to correct it. However, I realize that it's possible (though unlikely) that a user could input incorrect information an indefinite number of times and so I'm looking to implement a "while" loop to work around this.

In the case of the code below, I'm basically attempting to have it so that instead of the first ifelse entry I can enter into a loop by checking for the boolean value of "First_Name.isalpha():". However, I can't really think of a way to enter into it as when "First_Name.isalpha():" is true I don't need to enter into the loop as the entry is correct. When it's false, we skip over the loop altogether without having the entry corrected.

That basically prompts the question of whether or not there is a way to enter into a loop for when a boolean value is false. Or, if there's another creative solution that I'm not considering.

Thanks,

A Novice Coder

```
NewContact = "New Contact"

def NewEntry(NewContact):

# Obtain the contact's information:

    First_Name = input("Please enter your first name: ")
    Last_Name = input("Please enter your last name: ")
    Address = input("Please enter your street address: ")
    City = input("Please enter your city of residence: ")
    State = input("Please enter the 2 letter abbreviation of your state of residence: ")
    ZipCode = input("Please enter your zip code: ")
    Phone_Number = str(input("Please enter your phone number: "))

# Ensure all information inputted is correct:


    if First_Name.isalpha():
        First_Name = First_Name.strip()
        First_Name = First_Name.lower()
        First_Name = First_Name.title()
    else:
        First_Name = input("Please reenter your first name. Be sure to to include letters exclusively: ")

    if Last_Name.isalpha():
        Last_Name = Last_Name.strip()
        Last_Name = Last_Name.lower()
        Last_Name = Last_Name.title()
    else:
        Last_Name = input("Please reenter your first name. Be sure to to include letters exclusively: ")

# Organize inputted information:

    NewContact = Last_Name + ", " + First_Name
    FullAddress = Address + " " + City + ", " + State + " " + ZipCode

# Return information to writer to ensure correctness of information

# Write information onto document

    TheFile = open("AddressBook", "w")
    TheFile.write(str(NewContact) + "\n")
    TheFile.write(str(FullAddress) + "\n")
    TheFile.write(str(Phone_Number) + "\n")

    TheFile.close()

 NewEntry(NewContact)
```

Comment: are you talking about the `not` boolean operator?

Comment: Btw, don't use mixed-case names for variables or functions: `NewEntry, First_Name, TheFile`. That's very unpythonic and violates PEP-8 recommended style. See [this introduction](http://pymbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pep8.html) and  [tag:pep8]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the `not` operator, which inverts a boolean value:

```
>>> not False
True
>>> not True
False
>>> not "".isalpha()
True
>>> not "abc".isalpha()
False
```

You can tack it on the front of any expression that's a valid condition for an `if` or `while`.

Comment: Well shoot, now I feel really dumb. Not sure how I've avoided learning something so simple for so long now. Thank you!

Comment: @Pynchia wanna see one of the funniest simplest answers check the question I asked on the first day I started using python.

Comment: @DeliriousMistakes the one about the return value from a function?! Hahahaha, good one!

Comment: @Pynchia I had no idea what I was doing it was my first time using something other than `def main():`

Comment: @DeliriousMistakes you can see how badly I started out... I was yelling at the browser and feeling very frustrated...

Answer (score -1):

Use this structure

```
invalid = True
while invalid:
    ## get inputs

    ## validate inputs
    ## set invalid accordingly
```